# Microsoft Bot Framework (MBF) - can't get video from Kik channel

Tags: node.js, botframework, mbf

I can't get my bot approved on Kik because of the following reason:

> Your bot failed to respond to messages of the following types: start-chatting, video

I'll probably fix the start-chatting, but the video part is weird.

In other channels (e.g. Facebook Messenger) my bot intercept the video and can responds to it, but on Kik, it seems like I get no message at all when the user sends a video message.

Anyone familiar with that issue? Any help would be appreciated.
I'm using the Node.Js SDK.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. My bot service is running on Azure, and after 20 minutes of inactivity, the server is becoming idle and the response is delayed in about 15 seconds.